# Laravel get first item from collection if pivot table condition is true

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table

Let's assume I have the following many to many polymorphic relation in my database.

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
    stuff - string
```

I retrieve a post from databases.

```php
$post = Post::find(1);
```

How can I get the tags related to this post where `stuff == something` ? I want to create function so I can call it every time I need.

This code works :

```php
public function get_my_tag() {
    return $post->tags()->wherePivot('stuff', 'something')->first();
}
```

But it will retrieve it from database every time I call it. I need a way that stores $tag inside $post, so no matter how many times I call `get_my_tag()`, it should retrieve it from database only one time.

Comment: I guess you'll need to use eager loading `Post::with('tags')->find(1)`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I don't want to load all tags. Just an specific one

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```php
Post::with([
    'tags' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('any_field_on_tags_table', 'value');
    },
])->find(1);
```

<strike>You need to use `whereHas()` method</strike>

```php
Post::with('tags')->whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
    $query->where('any_field_on_tags_table', 'value');
})->find(1);
```